Resolving Circular Import Error in Python for Nested Submodules in a Forked Library
I am working on a Python project structured with a src directory that includes various scripts and a forked library submodule. The project's directory structure is as follows:

src/
├── script1.py
├── script2.py
└── doctr/
    ├── api
    ├── demo
    ├── docs
    ├── doctr/
    │   ├── contrib
    │   ├── datasets
    │   ├── file_utils.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── io
    │   ├── models
    │   ├── transforms
    │   ├── utils
    │   └── version.py
    |_________________

When trying to import modules from the nested doctr directory in the scripts like this:
from doctr.doctr.models import ocr_predictor, I am encountering circular import errors.
Here is the typical error message I receive:

ImportError: cannot import name 'VOCABS' from partially initialized module 'doctr.datasets' (most likely due to a circular import) (src/doctr/doctr/datasets/init.py)

What i have tried until now:

created an init.py file under the root of the submodule, did not help
changed the name of root directory file, no chance withh that as well


Unfortunately, the provided information (in my oppinion) wouldn't be enough to resolve you problem, if the problem is circular import error. The structure src\doctr\doctr\ doesn't look good. Why have you nested doctr ? Why don't you try to flatten your project structure with the removal of the additional doctr and try again ?

I have flattened it and  that solved the problem. My intention was to keep the lib as a submodule in my project, i was planning to customize it in a separate project and then use it here. But that is overcomplicating and i am not that fine programmer to know how to handle these issues.
Thank you for your help.
